# max memory size ignored in netbeans using windows

Tags: java, memory-management, netbeans

I am not sure if this is a valid stackoverflow question!

I have installed netbeans on a windows xp machine. However this machine has very limited memory. Since Netbeans uses most memory I wanted to limit the size of memory Netbeans uses.

From what I can read on this [page](https://performance.netbeans.org/howto/jvmswitches/) is that I can use either the `-J-Xmx256m` switch or the `–J-XX:MaxPermSize` switch inside a config file: *./etc/netbeans.conf*.

So I changed it like this:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
```

I tried both options, however Netbeans either doesn't starts up or doesn't uphold the new policy if it starts. When it starts I see a memory increase above the specified 256megabytes for netbeans in my task manager.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java there are more types of memory. Using **MaxPermSize** you are increasing the max of your permgen memory which is used to store "static" info about your classes. You want to increase the memory for your "dynamic" data. That is the heap and for this **-J-Xmx** is used. You could verify your settings using jvisualvm.

So to increase your heap try something like:

```
-J-Xmx512m
```

If you are using a 32 bit Java your memory is somewhat limited to I think 1g. If you are using invalid (too large) settings, Netbeans will not start.

The memory Netbeans shows in its memory display is the addition of PermGenSpace and Heap. Again: look into jvisualvm to control the used settings for each memory type.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to decrease memory usage not increase it. I already tried the Xmx option but that doesn't work either. Netbeans still refuses to uphold the new policy!

Comment: The memory Netbeans shows in its memory display is the addition of PermGenSpace and Heap. Maybe that is your problem. Again: look into jvisualvm to control the used settings for each memory type.

Comment: So in order to limit memory to 256 I have to set PemGen and heap both to 128?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried changing MaxPermSize to 128, but I ended up with a never ending splash screen so I gave up. Please update your answer with what you have in comments so I can accept it.

Comment: Dont split it half and half. The heap is in general more used. I dont know if it is enough for netbeans with many plugins to set its memorys to your settings.

Comment: Thanks wumpz, I am using the PHP version of Netbeans and I already have unistalled most plugins.

Comment: Deactivation of plugins should be enough. What kind of hardware are you using? Which version of Netbeans are you using? Netbeans needs pretty much memory, like other IDEs as well. My experience is that netbeans chooses quite good memory settings automatically if resources are small.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to know the difference between `-XX:MaxPermSize` and `-Xmx` spaces:

`-Xmx` specifies maximum memory allocation pool for a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) which contains:

- Eden Space (heap): The pool from which memory is initially allocated for most objects.
- Survivor Space (heap): The pool containing objects that have survived the garbage collection of the Eden space.
- Tenured Generation (heap): The pool containing objects that have existed for some time in the survivor space.

`-XX:MaxPermSize` is The pool containing all the reflective data of the virtual machine itself, such as class and method objects. With Java VMs that use class data sharing, this generation is divided into read-only and read-write areas.

Second: You have a wrong argument in your `netbeans_default_options` which is `-J-Xss2m`

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m ...
```

you need to change it to something like:

```
   netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xmx256m -J-Xms32m ...// or something like that
```